# Does ArcGIS linear distance tool calculate exact distance on ground?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, distance

We can calculate linear distance in ArcGIS Desktop.

Is the distance to be calculated the exact ground distance?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  What tool are you using to "calculate linear distance"?  Is there any reason why you suspect that it may not have "calculated the exact ground distance?"

Answer (score 2):

In short, no.

Distance calculations in ArcGIS are straight line distances between features. They do not take into account the Surface or 3D aspects of the relationship between features.

There have been two posts recently that discuss the 3D or Surface aspects of distance. See them here:

[https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272231/creating-buffer-using-dem-in-arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242607/creating-buffer-polygon-following-elevations-using-arcgis-desktop/242619#242619)

[Creating Buffer Polygon following Elevations using ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/242607/creating-buffer-polygon-following-elevations-using-arcgis-desktop/242619#242619)

In order to take into account on the ground distance, the ArcGIS Tools will need to know what that ground "looks" like. So you will need a surface from which you can run processes to calculate the distance along the ground. If you have access to 3D Analyst / Spatial Analyst you can create these surfaces.